# Get write error when use os.system or subprocess with multiple pipes in Python

Tags: python, os.system

When I try to run multiple bash commands using pipes in python using os.system or subprocess:

```
import os 
name = os.system('ps -ef|grep -v grep|egrep -om1 "CONFIGNAME (.+?) -"|cut -d " " -f2')
print name
```

I got what I need but with an error:

```
 name
 grep: write error
 0
```

Can somebody explain why I got this error but I did not get any error when I ran it in shell directly?

Comment: Weird, your example works on my Ubuntu machine. Could you list output of the bash command here?

Comment: sorry forgot to mention I am using Python 2.7 and CentOS 6.3  and the output from shell is "name" but in python I got "name" properly but with "grep: write error" which I could not find out why.  The "name" is a folder name which is in the ps -ef output.   Do you get any output from this command?

Comment: I got same error when running through `os.popen` <br/>
`grep: write error
tail: write error: Broken pipe
tail: write error` <br/>
While no error is showing when running through terminal command: `git log | tail -n  +6 | grep -n 'xyz' | head -1`.